# Spacing text in table cells

Tags: spacing, longtable

How do I to space these two cells on this way?

[image]

And not on this way:

[image]

Code:

```
\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|p{8cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Classe} & \textbf{Stéréotype} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{R\^ole}} \tabularnewline
\hline
\raisebox{-0.35cm}{Les classes de dialogues} \og Boundary \fg & \raisebox{-0.95cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/st_boundary}} & Elles permettent l'interaction entre l'IHM et les utilisateurs. Ces classes sont directement issues de l'analyse de maquette. \tabularnewline
\hline
\raisebox{-0.95cm}{Les classes de contr\^oles} \og Control \fg & \raisebox{-1.72cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/st_control}} & Ces classes modélisent la cinématique de l'application. Elles font la jonction entre les dilogues et les classes métiers en permettant aux différentes  vues de l'application de manipuler les informations détenues par un ou plusieurs objets métiers.\tabularnewline
\hline
\raisebox{-0.7cm}{Les classes entités} \og Entity \fg & \raisebox{-1.2cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/st_entity}} & Ces classes sont fénéralement persistantes, elles proviennent directement du mod\`ele du domaine et permettent \`a des données et des relations d'\^etre stockées dans des fichiers ou des bases de données. \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{} \\[-7pt] 
\caption[]{Description des classes d'analyse.}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
```

This is what I'm trying to make at final:

[image]

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, next time, post a compilable example...

You shouldn't use those `\raisebox`es to place material in your table.

Try using the `m` column specifier instead of `p` and add the `valign=C` option in the `\includegraphics` (requires the `adjustbox` package with option `export`).

Also, you can issue a `\par` if you want to put some text below some other.

Finally, to add some spacing between the table and its caption, load the `caption` package and issue the command

```
\captionsetup[longtable]{skip=1em}
```

instead of inserting the line

```
\multicolumn{3}{l}{} \\[-7pt]
```

in your table.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{skip=1em}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}|m{8cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Classe} & \textbf{Stéréotype} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{R\^ole}} \tabularnewline
\hline
Les classes de dialogues\par \og Boundary \fg &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,valign=C]{images/st_boundary} &
Elles permettent l'interaction entre l'IHM et les utilisateurs. Ces classes sont directement issues de l'analyse de maquette. \tabularnewline
\hline
Les classes de contr\^oles\par \og Control \fg &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,valign=C]{images/st_control} &
Ces classes modélisent la cinématique de l'application. Elles font la jonction entre les dilogues et les classes métiers en permettant aux différentes  vues de l'application de manipuler les informations détenues par un ou plusieurs objets métiers.\tabularnewline
\hline
Les classes entités\par \og Entity \fg &
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,valign=C]{images/st_entity} &
Ces classes sont fénéralement persistantes, elles proviennent directement du mod\`ele du domaine et permettent \`a des données et des relations d'\^etre stockées dans des fichiers ou des bases de données. \tabularnewline
\hline
\caption[]{Description des classes d'analyse.}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

P.S. In the `\includegraphics` I've changed `scale=0.7` to `width=1cm,height=1cm` for displaying purposes since I do not have your images. Turn them back in your document.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but, what I'm trying to do, is just to center vertically and horizontally the content of the two cells of `Control` & `Entity`. No need to change the design of other cells unless the code is misused.

Comment: @user3289501 So you want all cells to be top aligned, except the one with `Control` & `Entity`?

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: @user3289501 I've updated the answer. See if it helps with your real images.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much !! +1